# Same Database, Same SQL Version, Very different Performance

Tags: sql-server-2014

We are having a performance issue with a reasonable simple stored procedure, so we to a back up of the database and restored it on a simple test machine and on our replica of our production environment. The only differences in the machines and the databases is the hardware, one is in a VM with 8Gig RAM and 4 processsors, the other is a physical cluster 64Gig RAM and 8 processors.

We have the same version of SQL Server (2014 SP1) on both machines, both databases restored from the same back up. When we run, the one takes less than a second, the other takes 2 minutes 40 seconds producing the same result set of 2976 rows.

The main table involved only has circa 59K rows. The execution plans are nearly identical but but for the outputs on one of the clustered index scans

[image: Clustered Dev Machine]

[image: Virtual Machine]

So what is driving me nuts is how / why would an identical database on identical versions of SQL Server produce two wildly different actual number of rows (174822900 vs 58764) with 2975 executions vs 4 ??

This is the code being run

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;

DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[ngage_Tree_SelectClientData]
              @ParentId = 0,
              @FromDate = '2016-08-04 17:16:40.367',
              @UserGroupId = '1|',
              @MaxToReturn = 100000

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value;
```

and this is the code for the stored procedure iteself:

```
CREATE PROC dbo.ngage_Tree_SelectClientData
    @ParentId BIGINT
   ,@FromDate DATETIME2
   ,@UserGroupId VARCHAR(50)
   ,@MaxToReturn INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @parentHierarchyId HIERARCHYID = (SELECT HierarchyId
                                              FROM Tree
                                              WHERE Id = @ParentId);

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@MaxToReturn)
        t.Id, t.ParentId,
        t.Title, t.Ordinal, t.HelpTopicId, 
        t.IsFolder, t.SmallIcon, t.LargeIcon,
        t.CmsTemplateId, t.IsSystemFolder, 
        t.ContextMenu, t.DateModified,
        CASE 
           WHEN n2.[HierarchyId] IS NULL 
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
        END AS 'HasChildren',
        t.ToolTip,
        t.[HierarchyId].ToString() AS ParentIds, t.Depth
    FROM    
        Tree t
    INNER JOIN 
        TreeToUserGroups ttug ON ttug.TreeId = t.Id
                              AND ttug.ReadPermission = 1
                              AND ttug.UserGroupId IN (SELECT ResultList
                                                       FROM dbo.SplitCommaList(@UserGroupId, '|'))
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Tree n2 ON t.[HierarchyId] = n2.[HierarchyId].GetAncestor(1)
    WHERE   
        t.IsDeleted = 0
        AND t.IsArchived = 0
        AND t.DateModified > @FromDate
        AND (@ParentId = 0
             OR t.[HierarchyId].IsDescendantOf(@parentHierarchyId) = 1)
        AND t.Id NOT IN (SELECT Id
                         FROM Tree
                         WHERE (TreeObjectType = N'EcomProduct'
                                AND Title = N'(MISC) MISC')
                            OR (Title = N'Tag Groups'
                                AND TreeObjectType = N'TagRoot')
                        )
    ORDER BY 
        t.DateModified ASC;
END;
```

- https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj3dwBusMe7yqao2igQ-JZilD4fVzw DEV Plan XML
- https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aj3dwBusMe7yqao1JWD-w8sOhvrFhw VM Plan XML

Comment: Please post the execution plans as xml

Comment: Run update statistics with full scan on both of the tables  in the  instances involved

Comment: I have added links to the XML plans thanks for helping